# How to setup bash environment inside Torque PBS? Why source ~/.bashrc doesn't work?

Tags: bash, pbs, torque

I have successfully installed Torque PBS on my ubuntu server. Job submission is fine. However there is an annoying thing. I found bash environment is not right inside PBS

for example

```
echo 'echo $PATH > ~/res.txt' | qsub
```

and the content of res.txt is

```
/home/admin-pc/bin:/home/admin-pc/.local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin
```

This is definitely not what my PATH is.

So I tried

```
echo 'source ~/.bashrc;echo $PATH > ~/res.txt' | qsub
```

This doesn't work. It just output the same PATH

So I was wondering, maybe `~/.bashrc` is not the same inside PBS. So I tried

```
echo 'cat ~/.bashrc > ~/res.txt' | qsub
```

But the content of res.txt is exactly what my ~/.bashrc is.

This is really odd to me.

The only workaround I found is to use `bash -ic`

```
echo "bash -ic 'echo \$PATH > ~/res.txt'"|qsub
```

But this is so awkward. Is there any better way to make PBS automatic inherit bash environment?

Comment: Maybe the `-V` option of `qsub` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Thomas That is exactly what I want. Thank you so much